# Configuration xorg to 3 monitors

Tags: linux, xorg

I have 3 monitors and 2 videocards.

```
# ls /sys/class/drm/ 
card0 
card0-DP-1 
card0-HDMI-A-1 
card0-VGA-1 
card1 
card1-DVI-D-1 
card1-DVI-D-2 
card1-HDMI-A-2 
card1-VGA-2 
controlD64 
controlD65 
renderD128 
renderD129 
ttm 
version
```

Use drivers:

```
# lspci -k | grep VGA -A 3 
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09) 
   Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller 
   Kernel driver in use: i915 
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04) 
-- 
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107 [GeForce GTX 650] (rev a1) 
   Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd GK107 [GeForce GTX 650] 
   Kernel driver in use: nouveau 
   Kernel modules: nouveau
```

I try to configure xorg:

```
Section "Monitor" 
   Identifier   "LeftMonitor" 
EndSection 

Section "Monitor" 
   Identifier   "CentralMonitor" 
   Option      "RightOf" "LeftMonitor" 
EndSection 

Section "Monitor" 
   Identifier   "RightMonitor" 
   Option      "RightOf" "CentralMonitor" 
EndSection 

Section "Device" 
   Identifier   "Intel" 
   #Driver      "i915" 
   BusID      "PCI:0:2:0" 
   Option      "Monitor-VGA-1" "CentralMonitor" 
   Option      "Monitor-HDMI-1" "LeftMonitor" 
EndSection 

Section "Device" 
   Identifier   "NVIDIA" 
   Driver      "nouveau" 
   BusID      "PCI:1:0:0" 
   Option      "Monitor-DVI-D-2" "RightMonitor" 
EndSection 

Section "Screen" 
   Identifier   "LeftScreen" 
   Device      "Intel" 
   Monitor      "LeftMonitor" 
EndSection 

Section "Screen" 
   Identifier   "CentralScreen" 
   Device      "Intel" 
   Monitor      "CentralMonitor" 
EndSection 

Section "Screen" 
   Identifier   "RightScreen" 
   Device      "NVIDIA" 
   Monitor      "RightMonitor" 
EndSection
```

But when the PC is booting and working in text-mode, it works only one nvidia monitor (it's ok). When I run startx the two other monitors in video-mode work.

```
# xrandr --listmonitors 
Monitors: 2 
 0: +VGA-1 1920/476x1080/267+1920+0  VGA-1 
 1: +HDMI-1 1920/476x1080/267+0+0  HDMI-1
```

Xorg log:

```
[    16.538] 
X.Org X Server 1.18.4
Release Date: 2016-07-19
[    16.538] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[    16.538] Build Operating System: Linux 4.4.39-gentoo x86_64 Gentoo
[    16.538] Current Operating System: Linux nozdrin 4.4.39-gentoo #5 SMP Fri Jan 20 13:51:53 MSK 2017 x86_64
[    16.538] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-4.4.39-gentoo root=/dev/sda4 ro video=VGA-2:1920x1080@60
[    16.538] Build Date: 19 January 2017  07:23:24AM
[    16.538]  
[    16.538] Current version of pixman: 0.34.0
[    16.538]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[    16.538] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[    16.538] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Mon Jan 23 08:41:08 2017
[    16.573] (==) Using config directory: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[    16.573] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[    16.620] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[    16.620] (**) |-->Screen "LeftScreen" (0)
[    16.620] (**) |   |-->Monitor "LeftMonitor"
[    16.621] (**) |   |-->Device "Intel"
[    16.621] (**) |   |-->GPUDevice "NVIDIA"
[    16.621] (==) Automatically adding devices
[    16.621] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[    16.621] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[    16.635] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[    16.656] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/TTF/" does not exist.
[    16.656]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    16.656] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/OTF/" does not exist.
[    16.656]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    16.656] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/Type1/" does not exist.
[    16.656]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    16.657] (WW) `fonts.dir' not found (or not valid) in "/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/".
[    16.657]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    16.657]    (Run 'mkfontdir' on "/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/").
[    16.657] (WW) `fonts.dir' not found (or not valid) in "/usr/share/fonts/75dpi/".
[    16.657]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    16.657]    (Run 'mkfontdir' on "/usr/share/fonts/75dpi/").
[    16.657] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/misc/
[    16.657] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib64/xorg/modules"
[    16.657] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[    16.657] (II) Loader magic: 0x814d40
[    16.657] (II) Module ABI versions:
[    16.657]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[    16.657]    X.Org Video Driver: 20.0
[    16.657]    X.Org XInput driver : 22.1
[    16.657]    X.Org Server Extension : 9.0
[    16.657] (EE) dbus-core: error connecting to system bus: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.FileNotFound (Failed to connect to socket /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory)
[    16.657] (++) using VT number 1

[    16.658] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card1)
[    16.658] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[    16.804] (--) PCI: (0:0:2:0) 8086:0102:1458:d000 rev 9, Mem @ 0xf7400000/4194304, 0xd0000000/268435456, I/O @ 0x0000f000/64
[    16.804] (--) PCI:*(0:1:0:0) 10de:0fc6:1458:3568 rev 161, Mem @ 0xf6000000/16777216, 0xe0000000/268435456, 0xf0000000/33554432, I/O @ 0x0000e000/128, BIOS @ 0x????????/524288
[    16.804] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[    16.813] (II) Loading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[    16.970] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    16.970]    compiled for 1.18.4, module version = 1.0.0
[    16.970]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 9.0
[    16.970] (==) AIGLX enabled
[    16.970] (==) Matched nouveau as autoconfigured driver 0
[    16.970] (==) Matched nv as autoconfigured driver 1
[    16.970] (==) Matched intel as autoconfigured driver 2
[    16.970] (==) Matched nouveau as autoconfigured driver 3
[    16.970] (==) Matched nv as autoconfigured driver 4
[    16.970] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 5
[    16.970] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 6
[    16.970] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 7
[    16.970] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[    16.970] (II) LoadModule: "nouveau"
[    16.988] (II) Loading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/drivers/nouveau_drv.so
[    17.012] (II) Module nouveau: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    17.012]    compiled for 1.18.4, module version = 1.0.12
[    17.012]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    17.012]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 20.0
[    17.012] (II) LoadModule: "nv"
[    17.012] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module nv
[    17.012] (II) UnloadModule: "nv"
[    17.012] (II) Unloading nv
[    17.012] (EE) Failed to load module "nv" (module does not exist, 0)
[    17.012] (II) LoadModule: "intel"
[    17.012] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module intel
[    17.012] (II) UnloadModule: "intel"
[    17.012] (II) Unloading intel
[    17.012] (EE) Failed to load module "intel" (module does not exist, 0)
[    17.012] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[    17.012] (II) Loading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[    17.015] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    17.015]    compiled for 1.18.4, module version = 1.18.4
[    17.015]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    17.015]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 20.0
[    17.015] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[    17.015] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module fbdev
[    17.015] (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
[    17.015] (II) Unloading fbdev
[    17.015] (EE) Failed to load module "fbdev" (module does not exist, 0)
[    17.015] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[    17.015] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module vesa
[    17.015] (II) UnloadModule: "vesa"
[    17.015] (II) Unloading vesa
[    17.015] (EE) Failed to load module "vesa" (module does not exist, 0)
[    17.015] (II) NOUVEAU driver 
[    17.015] (II) NOUVEAU driver for NVIDIA chipset families :
[    17.015]    RIVA TNT        (NV04)
[    17.015]    RIVA TNT2       (NV05)
[    17.015]    GeForce 256     (NV10)
[    17.015]    GeForce 2       (NV11, NV15)
[    17.015]    GeForce 4MX     (NV17, NV18)
[    17.015]    GeForce 3       (NV20)
[    17.015]    GeForce 4Ti     (NV25, NV28)
[    17.015]    GeForce FX      (NV3x)
[    17.015]    GeForce 6       (NV4x)
[    17.015]    GeForce 7       (G7x)
[    17.015]    GeForce 8       (G8x)
[    17.015]    GeForce GTX 200 (NVA0)
[    17.015]    GeForce GTX 400 (NVC0)
[    17.015] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[    17.015] (II) [drm] nouveau interface version: 1.3.1
[    17.016] (II) modeset(1): using drv /dev/dri/card0
[    17.016] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[    17.016] (II) UnloadModule: "nouveau"
[    17.016] (II) modeset(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
    "LeftScreen" for depth/fbbpp 24/32
[    17.016] (==) modeset(0): Depth 24, (==) framebuffer bpp 32
[    17.016] (==) modeset(0): RGB weight 888
[    17.016] (==) modeset(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[    17.016] (II) modeset(0): No glamor support in the X Server
[    17.016] (II) modeset(0): ShadowFB: preferred YES, enabled YES
[    17.029] (II) modeset(0): Output VGA-1 using monitor section CentralMonitor
[    17.029] (**) modeset(0): Option "RightOf" "LeftMonitor"
[    17.042] (II) modeset(0): Output HDMI-1 using monitor section LeftMonitor
[    17.056] (II) modeset(0): Output DP-1 has no monitor section
[    17.069] (II) modeset(0): EDID for output VGA-1
[    17.069] (II) modeset(0): Manufacturer: VSC  Model: e02c  Serial#: 16843009
[    17.069] (II) modeset(0): Year: 2013  Week: 37
[    17.069] (II) modeset(0): EDID Version: 1.3
[    17.069] (II) modeset(0): Analog Display Input,  Input Voltage Level: 0.700/0.300 V
[    17.069] (II) modeset(0): Sync:  Separate  Composite  SyncOnGreen
[    17.069] (II) modeset(0): Max Image Size [cm]: horiz.: 48  vert.: 27
[    17.069] (II) modeset(0): Gamma: 2.20
[    17.069] (II) modeset(0): DPMS capabilities: Off; RGB/Color Display
[    17.069] (II) modeset(0): Default color space is primary color space
[    17.069] (II) modeset(0): First detailed timing is preferred mode
[    17.069] (II) modeset(0): redX: 0.653 redY: 0.336   greenX: 0.324 greenY: 0.612
[    17.069] (II) modeset(0): blueX: 0.151 blueY: 0.065   whiteX: 0.313 whiteY: 0.329
[    17.069] (II) modeset(0): Supported established timings:
[    17.069] (II) modeset(0): 720x400@70Hz
[    17.069] (II) modeset(0): 640x480@60Hz
[    17.069] (II) modeset(0): 640x480@67Hz
[    17.069] (II) modeset(0): 640x480@72Hz
[    17.069] (II) modeset(0): 640x480@75Hz
[    17.069] (II) modeset(0): 800x600@56Hz
[    17.069] (II) modeset(0): 800x600@60Hz
[    17.069] (II) modeset(0): 800x600@72Hz
[    17.069] (II) modeset(0): 800x600@75Hz
[    17.069] (II) modeset(0): 832x624@75Hz
[    17.069] (II) modeset(0): 1024x768@60Hz
[    17.069] (II) modeset(0): 1024x768@70Hz
[    17.069] (II) modeset(0): 1024x768@75Hz
[    17.069] (II) modeset(0): 1280x1024@75Hz
[    17.069] (II) modeset(0): 1152x864@75Hz
[    17.069] (II) modeset(0): Manufacturer's mask: 0
[    17.069] (II) modeset(0): Supported standard timings:
[    17.069] (II) modeset(0): #0: hsize: 1680  vsize 1050  refresh: 60  vid: 179
[    17.069] (II) modeset(0): #1: hsize: 1600  vsize 1200  refresh: 60  vid: 16553
[    17.069] (II) modeset(0): #2: hsize: 1440  vsize 900  refresh: 60  vid: 149
[    17.069] (II) modeset(0): #3: hsize: 1400  vsize 1050  refresh: 60  vid: 16528
[    17.069] (II) modeset(0): #4: hsize: 1280  vsize 1024  refresh: 60  vid: 32897
[    17.069] (II) modeset(0): #5: hsize: 1280  vsize 960  refresh: 60  vid: 16513
[    17.069] (II) modeset(0): #6: hsize: 1152  vsize 864  refresh: 75  vid: 20337
[    17.069] (II) modeset(0): Supported detailed timing:
[    17.069] (II) modeset(0): clock: 148.5 MHz   Image Size:  476 x 267 mm
[    17.069] (II) modeset(0): h_active: 1920  h_sync: 2008  h_sync_end 2052 h_blank_end 2200 h_border: 0
[    17.069] (II) modeset(0): v_active: 1080  v_sync: 1084  v_sync_end 1089 v_blanking: 1125 v_border: 0
[    17.069] (II) modeset(0): Serial No: TFA133729840
[    17.069] (II) modeset(0): Ranges: V min: 50 V max: 76 Hz, H min: 24 H max: 83 kHz, PixClock max 215 MHz
[    17.069] (II) modeset(0): Monitor name: VX2270 SERIES
[    17.069] (II) modeset(0): EDID (in hex):
[    17.069] (II) modeset(0):   00ffffffffffff005a632ce001010101
[    17.069] (II) modeset(0):   251701030e301b782e43f5a756539c26
[    17.069] (II) modeset(0):   105054bfef80b300a940950090408180
[    17.069] (II) modeset(0):   8140714f0101023a801871382d40582c
[    17.069] (II) modeset(0):   4500dc0b1100001e000000ff00544641
[    17.069] (II) modeset(0):   3133333732393834300a000000fd0032
[    17.069] (II) modeset(0):   4c185315000a202020202020000000fc
[    17.069] (II) modeset(0):   005658323237302053455249455300a2
[    17.069] (II) modeset(0): Printing probed modes for output VGA-1
[    17.069] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x60.0  148.50  1920 2008 2052 2200  1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync (67.5 kHz eP)
[    17.069] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1600x1200"x60.0  162.00  1600 1664 1856 2160  1200 1201 1204 1250 +hsync +vsync (75.0 kHz e)
[    17.069] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1680x1050"x60.0  146.25  1680 1784 1960 2240  1050 1053 1059 1089 -hsync +vsync (65.3 kHz e)
[    17.069] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1400x1050"x60.0  121.75  1400 1488 1632 1864  1050 1053 1057 1089 -hsync +vsync (65.3 kHz e)
[    17.069] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x75.0  135.00  1280 1296 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (80.0 kHz e)
[    17.069] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x60.0  108.00  1280 1328 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (64.0 kHz e)
[    17.069] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1440x900"x59.9  106.50  1440 1520 1672 1904  900 903 909 934 -hsync +vsync (55.9 kHz e)
[    17.069] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1280x960"x60.0  108.00  1280 1376 1488 1800  960 961 964 1000 +hsync +vsync (60.0 kHz e)
[    17.069] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1152x864"x75.0  108.00  1152 1216 1344 1600  864 865 868 900 +hsync +vsync (67.5 kHz e)
[    17.069] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1024x768"x75.1   78.80  1024 1040 1136 1312  768 769 772 800 +hsync +vsync (60.1 kHz e)
[    17.069] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1024x768"x70.1   75.00  1024 1048 1184 1328  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (56.5 kHz e)
[    17.069] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1024x768"x60.0   65.00  1024 1048 1184 1344  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (48.4 kHz e)
[    17.069] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "832x624"x74.6   57.28  832 864 928 1152  624 625 628 667 -hsync -vsync (49.7 kHz e)
[    17.069] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "800x600"x72.2   50.00  800 856 976 1040  600 637 643 666 +hsync +vsync (48.1 kHz e)
[    17.069] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "800x600"x75.0   49.50  800 816 896 1056  600 601 604 625 +hsync +vsync (46.9 kHz e)
[    17.069] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "800x600"x60.3   40.00  800 840 968 1056  600 601 605 628 +hsync +vsync (37.9 kHz e)
[    17.069] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "800x600"x56.2   36.00  800 824 896 1024  600 601 603 625 +hsync +vsync (35.2 kHz e)
[    17.069] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "640x480"x75.0   31.50  640 656 720 840  480 481 484 500 -hsync -vsync (37.5 kHz e)
[    17.069] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "640x480"x72.8   31.50  640 664 704 832  480 489 491 520 -hsync -vsync (37.9 kHz e)
[    17.069] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "640x480"x66.7   30.24  640 704 768 864  480 483 486 525 -hsync -vsync (35.0 kHz e)
[    17.069] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "640x480"x60.0   25.20  640 656 752 800  480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[    17.069] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "720x400"x70.1   28.32  720 738 846 900  400 412 414 449 -hsync +vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[    17.082] (II) modeset(0): EDID for output HDMI-1
[    17.082] (II) modeset(0): Manufacturer: VSC  Model: e02c  Serial#: 16843009
[    17.082] (II) modeset(0): Year: 2013  Week: 26
[    17.082] (II) modeset(0): EDID Version: 1.3
[    17.082] (II) modeset(0): Digital Display Input
[    17.082] (II) modeset(0): Max Image Size [cm]: horiz.: 48  vert.: 27
[    17.082] (II) modeset(0): Gamma: 2.20
[    17.082] (II) modeset(0): DPMS capabilities: Off
[    17.082] (II) modeset(0): Supported color encodings: RGB 4:4:4 YCrCb 4:4:4 
[    17.082] (II) modeset(0): Default color space is primary color space
[    17.082] (II) modeset(0): First detailed timing is preferred mode
[    17.082] (II) modeset(0): redX: 0.653 redY: 0.336   greenX: 0.324 greenY: 0.612
[    17.082] (II) modeset(0): blueX: 0.151 blueY: 0.065   whiteX: 0.313 whiteY: 0.329
[    17.082] (II) modeset(0): Supported established timings:
[    17.082] (II) modeset(0): 720x400@70Hz
[    17.082] (II) modeset(0): 640x480@60Hz
[    17.082] (II) modeset(0): 640x480@67Hz
[    17.082] (II) modeset(0): 640x480@72Hz
[    17.082] (II) modeset(0): 640x480@75Hz
[    17.082] (II) modeset(0): 800x600@56Hz
[    17.082] (II) modeset(0): 800x600@60Hz
[    17.082] (II) modeset(0): 800x600@72Hz
[    17.082] (II) modeset(0): 800x600@75Hz
[    17.082] (II) modeset(0): 832x624@75Hz
[    17.082] (II) modeset(0): 1024x768@60Hz
[    17.082] (II) modeset(0): 1024x768@70Hz
[    17.082] (II) modeset(0): 1024x768@75Hz
[    17.082] (II) modeset(0): 1280x1024@75Hz
[    17.082] (II) modeset(0): 1152x864@75Hz
[    17.082] (II) modeset(0): Manufacturer's mask: 0
[    17.082] (II) modeset(0): Supported standard timings:
[    17.082] (II) modeset(0): #0: hsize: 1680  vsize 1050  refresh: 60  vid: 179
[    17.082] (II) modeset(0): #1: hsize: 1600  vsize 1200  refresh: 60  vid: 16553
[    17.082] (II) modeset(0): #2: hsize: 1440  vsize 900  refresh: 60  vid: 149
[    17.082] (II) modeset(0): #3: hsize: 1400  vsize 1050  refresh: 60  vid: 16528
[    17.082] (II) modeset(0): #4: hsize: 1280  vsize 1024  refresh: 60  vid: 32897
[    17.082] (II) modeset(0): #5: hsize: 1280  vsize 960  refresh: 60  vid: 16513
[    17.082] (II) modeset(0): #6: hsize: 1152  vsize 864  refresh: 75  vid: 20337
[    17.082] (II) modeset(0): #7: hsize: 640  vsize 400  refresh: 70  vid: 2609
[    17.082] (II) modeset(0): Supported detailed timing:
[    17.082] (II) modeset(0): clock: 148.5 MHz   Image Size:  476 x 267 mm
[    17.082] (II) modeset(0): h_active: 1920  h_sync: 2008  h_sync_end 2052 h_blank_end 2200 h_border: 0
[    17.082] (II) modeset(0): v_active: 1080  v_sync: 1084  v_sync_end 1089 v_blanking: 1125 v_border: 0
[    17.082] (II) modeset(0): Serial No: TFA132600479
[    17.082] (II) modeset(0): Ranges: V min: 50 V max: 76 Hz, H min: 24 H max: 83 kHz, PixClock max 185 MHz
[    17.082] (II) modeset(0): Monitor name: VX2270 SERIES
[    17.082] (II) modeset(0): EDID (in hex):
[    17.082] (II) modeset(0):   00ffffffffffff005a632ce001010101
[    17.082] (II) modeset(0):   1a17010380301b782e43f5a756539c26
[    17.082] (II) modeset(0):   105054bfef80b300a940950090408180
[    17.082] (II) modeset(0):   8140714f310a023a801871382d40582c
[    17.082] (II) modeset(0):   4500dc0b1100001e000000ff00544641
[    17.082] (II) modeset(0):   3133323630303437390a000000fd0032
[    17.082] (II) modeset(0):   4c185312000a202020202020000000fc
[    17.082] (II) modeset(0):   0056583232373020534552494553000a
[    17.082] (II) modeset(0): Printing probed modes for output HDMI-1
[    17.082] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x60.0  148.50  1920 2008 2052 2200  1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync (67.5 kHz eP)
[    17.082] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1600x1200"x60.0  162.00  1600 1664 1856 2160  1200 1201 1204 1250 +hsync +vsync (75.0 kHz e)
[    17.082] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1680x1050"x59.9  119.00  1680 1728 1760 1840  1050 1053 1059 1080 +hsync -vsync (64.7 kHz e)
[    17.082] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1400x1050"x59.9  101.00  1400 1448 1480 1560  1050 1053 1057 1080 +hsync -vsync (64.7 kHz e)
[    17.082] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x75.0  135.00  1280 1296 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (80.0 kHz e)
[    17.082] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x60.0  108.00  1280 1328 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (64.0 kHz e)
[    17.082] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1440x900"x59.9   88.75  1440 1488 1520 1600  900 903 909 926 +hsync -vsync (55.5 kHz e)
[    17.082] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1280x960"x60.0  108.00  1280 1376 1488 1800  960 961 964 1000 +hsync +vsync (60.0 kHz e)
[    17.082] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1152x864"x75.0  108.00  1152 1216 1344 1600  864 865 868 900 +hsync +vsync (67.5 kHz e)
[    17.082] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1024x768"x75.1   78.80  1024 1040 1136 1312  768 769 772 800 +hsync +vsync (60.1 kHz e)
[    17.082] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1024x768"x70.1   75.00  1024 1048 1184 1328  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (56.5 kHz e)
[    17.082] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1024x768"x60.0   65.00  1024 1048 1184 1344  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (48.4 kHz e)
[    17.082] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "832x624"x74.6   57.28  832 864 928 1152  624 625 628 667 -hsync -vsync (49.7 kHz e)
[    17.082] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "800x600"x72.2   50.00  800 856 976 1040  600 637 643 666 +hsync +vsync (48.1 kHz e)
[    17.082] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "800x600"x75.0   49.50  800 816 896 1056  600 601 604 625 +hsync +vsync (46.9 kHz e)
[    17.082] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "800x600"x60.3   40.00  800 840 968 1056  600 601 605 628 +hsync +vsync (37.9 kHz e)
[    17.082] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "800x600"x56.2   36.00  800 824 896 1024  600 601 603 625 +hsync +vsync (35.2 kHz e)
[    17.082] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "640x480"x75.0   31.50  640 656 720 840  480 481 484 500 -hsync -vsync (37.5 kHz e)
[    17.082] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "640x480"x72.8   31.50  640 664 704 832  480 489 491 520 -hsync -vsync (37.9 kHz e)
[    17.082] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "640x480"x66.7   30.24  640 704 768 864  480 483 486 525 -hsync -vsync (35.0 kHz e)
[    17.082] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "640x480"x60.0   25.20  640 656 752 800  480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[    17.082] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "720x400"x70.1   28.32  720 738 846 900  400 412 414 449 -hsync +vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[    17.082] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "640x400"x70.0   23.35  640 656 720 800  400 401 404 417 -hsync +vsync (29.2 kHz)
[    17.097] (II) modeset(0): EDID for output DP-1
[    17.097] (II) modeset(0): Output VGA-1 connected
[    17.097] (II) modeset(0): Output HDMI-1 connected
[    17.097] (II) modeset(0): Output DP-1 disconnected
[    17.097] (II) modeset(0): Using user preference for initial modes
[    17.097] (II) modeset(0): Output VGA-1 using initial mode 1920x1080 +0+0
[    17.097] (II) modeset(0): Output HDMI-1 using initial mode 1920x1080 +0+0
[    17.097] (II) modeset(0): Using default gamma of (1.0, 1.0, 1.0) unless otherwise stated.
[    17.097] (==) modeset(0): DPI set to (96, 96)
[    17.097] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
[    17.097] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[    17.097] (II) Loading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/libfb.so
[    17.105] (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    17.105]    compiled for 1.18.4, module version = 1.0.0
[    17.105]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[    17.105] (II) Loading sub module "shadow"
[    17.105] (II) LoadModule: "shadow"
[    17.105] (II) Loading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/libshadow.so
[    17.114] (II) Module shadow: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    17.114]    compiled for 1.18.4, module version = 1.1.0
[    17.114]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[    17.114] (==) Depth 24 pixmap format is 32 bpp
[    17.126] (==) modeset(0): Backing store enabled
[    17.126] (==) modeset(0): Silken mouse enabled
[    17.126] (II) modeset(0): RandR 1.2 enabled, ignore the following RandR disabled message.
[    17.168] (==) modeset(0): DPMS enabled
[    17.201] (--) RandR disabled
[    17.206] (II) AIGLX: Screen 0 is not DRI2 capable
[    17.206] (EE) AIGLX: reverting to software rendering
[    18.018] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer
[    18.019] (II) AIGLX: Loaded and initialized swrast
[    18.019] (II) GLX: Initialized DRISWRAST GL provider for screen 0
[    18.019] (II) modeset(0): Damage tracking initialized
[    18.019] (II) modeset(0): Setting screen physical size to 1016 x 285
[    18.308] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install `nvidia` driver and run `nvidia-settings`

X.org:

```
# nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings 
# nvidia-settings:  version 375.26  (portage@nozdrin)  Tue Jan 24 07:57:41 MSK 2017 

# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig 
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 375.26  (buildmeister@swio-display-x86-rhel47-01)  Thu Dec  8 19:07:46 PST 2016 

Section "ServerLayout" 

    #InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard" 
    #InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer" 
# Removed Option "Xinerama" "0" 
# Removed Option "Xinerama" "1" 
    Identifier     "Layout0" 
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0 
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard" 
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer" 
    Option         "Xinerama" "0" 
EndSection 

Section "Files" 
EndSection 

Section "InputDevice" 

    # generated from default 
    Identifier     "Keyboard0" 
    Driver         "kbd" 
EndSection 

Section "InputDevice" 

    # generated from data in "/etc/conf.d/gpm" 
    Identifier     "Mouse0" 
    Driver         "mouse" 
    Option         "Protocol" 
    Option         "Device" "/dev/input/mice" 
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no" 
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5" 
EndSection 

Section "Monitor" 
    Identifier     "Monitor0" 
    VendorName     "Unknown" 
    ModelName      "ViewSonic VX2270 SERIES" 
    HorizSync       24.0 - 83.0 
    VertRefresh     50.0 - 76.0 
    Option         "DPMS" 
EndSection 

Section "Monitor" 
    Identifier     "Monitor1" 
    VendorName     "Unknown" 
    ModelName      "ViewSonic VX2270 SERIES" 
    HorizSync       24.0 - 83.0 
    VertRefresh     50.0 - 76.0 
EndSection 

Section "Monitor" 
    Identifier     "Monitor2" 
    VendorName     "Unknown" 
    ModelName      "ViewSonic VX2270 SERIES" 
    HorizSync       24.0 - 83.0 
    VertRefresh     50.0 - 76.0 
EndSection 

Section "Device" 
    Identifier     "Device0" 
    Driver         "nvidia" 
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation" 
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 650" 
EndSection 

Section "Device" 
    Identifier     "Device1" 
    Driver         "nvidia" 
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation" 
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 650" 
    BusID          "PCI:1:0:0" 
    Screen          1 
EndSection 

Section "Device" 
    Identifier     "Device2" 
    Driver         "nvidia" 
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation" 
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 650" 
    BusID          "PCI:1:0:0" 
    Screen          2 
EndSection 

Section "Screen" 

# Removed Option "metamodes" "VGA-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0, DVI-D-1: nvidia-auto-select +1920+0, DVI-D-0: nvidia-auto-select +3840+0" 
# Removed Option "metamodes" "VGA-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0" 
# Removed Option "metamodes" "DVI-D-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0" 
    Identifier     "Screen0" 
    Device         "Device0" 
    Monitor        "Monitor0" 
    DefaultDepth    24 
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "CRT-0" 
    Option         "Stereo" "0" 
    Option         "metamodes" "DVI-D-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0, DVI-D-1: nvidia-auto-select +3840+0, VGA-0: nvidia-auto-select +1920+0" 
    Option         "SLI" "Off" 
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off" 
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off" 
    SubSection     "Display" 
        Depth       24 
    EndSubSection 
EndSection 

Section "Screen" 

# Removed Option "metamodes" "DVI-D-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0" 
    Identifier     "Screen1" 
    Device         "Device1" 
    Monitor        "Monitor1" 
    DefaultDepth    24 
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-0" 
    Option         "Stereo" "0" 
    Option         "metamodes" "VGA-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0" 
    Option         "SLI" "Off" 
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off" 
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off" 
    SubSection     "Display" 
        Depth       24 
    EndSubSection 
EndSection 

Section "Screen" 
    Identifier     "Screen2" 
    Device         "Device2" 
    Monitor        "Monitor2" 
    DefaultDepth    24 
    Option         "Stereo" "0" 
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-2" 
    Option         "metamodes" "DVI-D-1: nvidia-auto-select +0+0" 
    Option         "SLI" "Off" 
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off" 
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off" 
    SubSection     "Display" 
        Depth       24 
    EndSubSection 
EndSection
```